# After 15000 iterations, getting "error: can't allocate region"-- no memory warning

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

Points:  Using ARC;
full error is:

> malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)**
>    error: can't allocate region
>   ** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

four times.

The only code of any substance to the question is:

```
-(void)iterate:(NSString *)string{
    frontString = NULL;
    backString = NULL;
    arrayOfNumbers = NULL;
    backwardArrayOfNumbers = NULL;
    nextString = NULL;
    nextArrayOfNumbers = NULL;
    nextArrayOfNumbers = [NSMutableArray new];
    nextString = [NSMutableString new];
    backwardArrayOfNumbers = [NSMutableArray new];
    arrayOfNumbers = [NSMutableArray new];
    frontString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    backString = [NSMutableString new];
    if (string.length > 1) {
        iteration++;
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < string.length; ++i) {
            NSString *sub = [string substringWithRange:(NSRange){i, 1}];
            [arrayOfNumbers addObject:sub];
            NSString *back = [string substringWithRange:(NSRange){string.length-(i+1), 1}];
            [backwardArrayOfNumbers addObject:back];
            [backString appendString:back];
            sub = NULL;
            back = NULL;
        }

        if ([frontString isEqualToString:backString]) {
            [palindromicNumberTextView setText:string];
            [iterationLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", iteration]];
        } else {
            int carrier = 0;
            for (long long j = arrayOfNumbers.count-1; j > -1; --j) {
                int a = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:j] intValue];
                int b = [[backwardArrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:j] intValue];
                //NSLog(@"a = %i, b = %i", a, b);

                int c = a+b+carrier;
                if (c > 9) {
                    c = c-10;
                    carrier = 1;
                } else {
                    carrier = 0;
                }

                [nextArrayOfNumbers addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", c]];
                if (carrier == 1 && (nextArrayOfNumbers.count == arrayOfNumbers.count)) {
                    [nextArrayOfNumbers addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", carrier]];
                }
                //NSLog(@"nextArrayOfNumbers = %@", nextArrayOfNumbers);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nextArrayOfNumbers.count; ++i) {
                NSString *back = [nextArrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex: nextArrayOfNumbers.count-(i+1)];
                //NSLog(@"back = %@", back);
                [nextString appendString:back];
                back = NULL;

            }
            if (iteration%1000 == 0) {
                NSLog(@"iteration %ld; count:%u", iteration, nextArrayOfNumbers.count);
            }
            //NSLog(@"iteration %ld", iteration);
            [self iterate:nextString];
        }
    }
}
```

15,000+ iterations later, crash + error, with no memory warning:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    NSLog(@"Error near iteration %ld", iteration);
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  Converting between `CString` and `NSString` is a pain with ARC.  So I went with `@autoreleasepool{}` inside the loops (and `nil` rather than `NULL`)  and that has dramatically reduced memory usage.  I'm up over 50k iterations.

Comment: Am I reading this right?  Are you seriously going 15,000 levels deep in recursion, and you're wondering why you're running out of memory?

Comment: No, I'm wondering why I'm running out of memory with an NSMutableArray that is less than a third the size of what I've seen in a functional environment.  Does the process of recursion, itself, eat memory?

Comment: Every time you recurse, you create a new copy of these arrays.

Comment: But each of the arrays is deallocated with ARC, once I set them to NULL, yes?

Answer (score 1):

So the program itself has some issues if it's using that much memory -- you can reduce memory usage of this algo significantly.

Anyways, you won't get a memory warning *if* this takes place on the main thread. The memory warning is made on the main thread, and you give it no chance to handle the warning because you exhaust memory before the main thread's run loop has another chance to do its usual work (such as handle memory warnings or handle other events).

Perhaps you would see something different if this happened on a secondary thread, but that would not solve the root of the problem.

Comment: "you can reduce memory usage of this algo significantly."  -- How is that?

Comment: iterate, don't recurse, explicitly create and destroy autorelease pools often, autorelease nothing (in your implementation), use numbers instead of strings when you are storing just numbers, use c types where possible. those ivars you NULL at the entrance - do you release them? then review and profile, and have another pass at it. the meat of the implementaton could be peformed using a small amount of stack space with C types. a c implementation will also execute many many many many times faster. even using CF-types with no autoreleasing should help you understand the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

You are solving a problem recursively which fills up memory.

Your computer has to keep track of where to go when it finishes each of 15,000 cycles.  That can become a lot of space.

If it is possible to make this "tail recursive" you could save space.  For instance:

```
"bad" recursion which saves in memory 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2
int factorial (int x)
{
  if (x > 1)
  {
     return (x + recursion (x - 1));
  }
  else return x;
}
```

//

```
good recursion start with y = 1
only saves in memory two integers, updating them every cycle.
int factorial (int x, int y)
{
  if (x > 1)
  {
     return factorial (x - 1, (x * y));
  }
  else return x;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is nonsense to me, which means I'm missing an important point.  How does this relate to my code?